# In database terms, what is the difference between replication and decentralisation?

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, replication, database

I am currently researching different databases to use for my next project. I was wanting to use a decentralized database. For example Apache Cassandra claims to be decentralized. MongoDB however says it uses replication. From what I can see, as far as these databases are concerned, replication and decentralization are basically the same thing. Is that correct or is there some difference/feature between decentralization and replication that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you look at my answer and tell me if it was useful or not. Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no, replication and decentralization are two different things. As a simple example, let's say you have three instances (i1, i2 and i3) that replicate the same data. You also have a client that fetches data from only i1. If i1 goes down you will still have the data replicated to i2 and i3 as a backup. But since i1 is down the client has no way of getting the data. This an example of a centralized database with single point of failure.

A centralized database has a centralized location that the majority of requests goes through. It could, as in Mongo DB's case be instances that route queries to instances that can handle the query.

A decentralized database is obviously the opposite. In Cassandra any node in a cluster can handle any request. This node is called the coordinator for the request. The node then reads/writes data from/to the nodes that are responsible for that data before returning a result to the client.

Answer (score 1):

**Decentralization** means that there should be no single point of failure in your application architecture. These systems will provide deployment scheme, where there's no leader (or master) elected during the service life-cycle. These are often deliver services in a peer-to-peer fashion.

**Replication** means, that simply your data is copied over to another server instance to ensure redundancy and failure tolerance. Client requests can still be served from copies, but your system should ensure some level of *"consistency"*, when making copies.

**Cassandra** serves requests in a peer-to-peer fashion. Meaning that clients can initiate requests to any node participating in the cluster. It also provides replication and tunable consistency.

**MongoDB** offers master/slave deployment, so it's not considered as decentralized. You can deliver a multi-master, to ensure that requests can still be served if master node goes down. It also provides replication out-of-the box.

---

**Links**

- [Cassandra's tunable consistency](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html)
- [MongoDB's master-slave configuration](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/master-slave/)
- [Introduction to Cassandra's architecture](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-apache-cassandras)